# (OOP) MVC Pattern - Should the View have unrestricted access to the Model's data?

Tags: java, oop, model-view-controller, interface

I have searched for similar questions in StackOverflow but my doubt still remains.

Supose im using the MVC pattern on a Chess game implemented in Java.

Upon the need for refreshing the View's representation of the Chess board (e.g., a 2D array of `Cell` objects, each of which may or not contain a `ChessPiece` object), should i, for example, "hide" these objects behind a restrictive interface which only contains methods the View needs, or should i just pass the data "as is" to the view (thus allowing the View to effectively change some of the data)?

This questions has bugged me since i learned about the MVC design pattern, as i don't like to publicly expose all data throughout an entire application, and my goal is to know which method would be the safest.

Thank you.

Comment: I think that it's fine for the view to gain access to the model's state as long as there is no way for the view to directly mutate this state. Often the issue is more of *when* should the model's state be queried.

Comment: The View doesn't directly access the Model's state. The situation is that, upon a refresh request, the Controller will query the Model for the Chess Board. At this point, the question is whether the Controller should or not "mask" this data before delivering it to the View.
If the question isn't clear enough i can easily edit it.

Comment: The bottom line is the same: the view should not be *allowed* to be able to modify the model's data.